# how to convert Word document to pdf conserving the same template using python

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, ms-word

I need to convert a word document to pdf conserving the same template used to generated the word document using python script
Note : I don't have word application installed in my machine and I don't have permission to install it
Is there a solution using python libraries , the template should be conserved

Answer (score 0):

you can use the python-docx and pdf2docx libraries to convert a Word document to a PDF while preserving the template. Get in mind that this library may need word instaled on your computer. Next lines are example:

```
from docx2pdf import convert
# Convert a single file - here maybe need to set file path
convert("input.docx", "output.pdf")
# Convert all files in a directory
convert("my_docx_folder/")
```

Alternatively, you can use the spire.doc library, which doesn’t require Word to be installed. As example you can use this:

```
from spire.doc import Document, FileFormat
# Create a Document object
document = Document()
# Load the .docx file
document.LoadFromFile("sample.docx")
# Save the document as a PDF
document.SaveToFile("output.pdf", FileFormat.PDF)
```

https://dev.to/codingco/how-to-convert-word-doc-docx-to-pdf-in-python-308h
this also can help you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you , this works for me , however in the pdf generated I have tis warning displayed : Evaluation Warning: The document was created with Spire.Doc for Python

Comment: this messege appears when you are using the evaluation version of the Sprire.Doc library. 
To solve this problem you can: - upgrade to the commercial version of Spire.Doc, - Ensure you are using the free version (the free version of Spire.Doc shold not display this warning. and last you can check this, https://www.e-iceblue.com/forum/remove-evaluation-warning-text-from-word-file-t7042.html its for .NET but its almost the same problem. Hope this helps! Good luck

Comment: Also , the warning apears , is there another solution to make the conversion without having word office installed and conserving the same template as the word document